# What is the ending in Super Mario Galaxy 2?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I've collected 241 stars in Super Mario Galaxy 2. I'm missing the last one, where you have to go through a very complex level without dying. I tried to beat this level for maybe 3-4 hours, but then decided it just wasn't worth it.

What would happen if I were patient enough to actually finish the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rosalina will join your ship, and you also get a "Congratulations!" message from Nintendo sent to your inbox: